# Why const lifetime elision does not work with slice in a struct impl?

Tags: rust, lifetime

The following [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#static-lifetime-elision) works:

```rust
struct X;
impl X { 
    const ONE: &str = "one"; 
}
```

Why does the [following](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=257861287b47554a1fe73dcdfa0d6fcd) not work?

```rust
struct X;
impl X {
    const TWO: &[&str] = &["two"];
}
```

The compiler complains about differing lifetimes when all lifetimes should be `'static`:

```
error[E0491]: in type `&[&str]`, reference has a longer lifetime than the data it references
 --> src/lib.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     const TWO: &[&str] = &["two"];
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Interestingly, *outside* of the `impl` block, the code works. But this should make no difference to the lifetimes.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [known bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/114706)
caused because

> ```rust
> impl Foo {
>   const CONST: &str = "";
> }
> ```
>
> Is desugaring to:
>
> ```rust
> impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
>   const CONST: &'a str = "";
> }
> ```

A workaround is to just specify the `'static` lifetime explicitly instead:

```rust
struct X;
impl X {
    const TWO: &[&'static str] = &["two"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The lifetime elision in many cases seems confusing/specific/opinionated. I'm curious what the history is here. Was elision part of the first release, or added on after real world examples popped up where it was deemed helpful? Knowing when I need to add the explicit lifetimes is my current struggle while learning this language!